# The code is stuck at .push in nodejs and nothing further is executed

Tags: node.js

The code is stuck at .push in nodejs and nothing further is executed tried modifying array in all possible ways an object needs to be pushed for further use
here is the piece of code

```
  router.post('/addtocart', function (req, res, next) {
    var cartadd = [];
    addtocart = {
        productId: req.body.productId,
        product_name: req.body.pname,
        product_price: req.body.price,
        product_qty: req.body.adult,
        vendor_id: req.body.vendor_id,
        ticket_name: req.user.first_name,
        ticket_email: req.user.email,
    }
    console.log(addtocart);
    **cartadd.push(addtocart);**//stuck at this point
    var addtocart = new Acart({
        user: {
            id: req.user._id,
            first_name: req.user.first_name,
            last_name: req.user.last_name,
            email: req.user.email,
            telephone: req.user.telephone
        },
        cart: cartadd,
        paymentId: 1234, // Adding Dummmy payment id
        checkin: req.body.arrival,
        checkout: req.body.depart,
        status: 'pending',
        total: req.body.price
    });
    addtocart.save(function (err, orderdata) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("1196Error: " + err.message)
            req.flash('error', 'Unable to save order... ' + err.message);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        req.flash('success', "Added to Cart!");

        });
        // return res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: could you outline your process for determining that code was stuck there?

Comment: [Debug your code using `node --inspect-brk NAME_OF_SERVER.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) and see if there are any exceptions being raised.  You can use Chrome as the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

could not figure the exact error but yeah by trial and error this code works fine but yeah its no much change if someone could give it a reason then it would be great

```
 router.post('/addtocart', function (req, res, next) {
    var cartlist=[];
    addtocart = {
        productId: req.body.productId,
        product_name: req.body.pname,
        product_price: req.body.price,
        product_qty: req.body.adult,
        vendor_id: req.body.vendor_id,
        ticket_name: req.user.first_name,
        ticket_email: req.user.email,
    }
    console.log(addtocart);
    cartlist.push(addtocart);
    console.log("cartlist"+cartlist);
    var addtocart = new Acart({
        user: {
            id: req.user._id,
            first_name: req.user.first_name,
            last_name: req.user.last_name,
            email: req.user.email,
            telephone: req.user.telephone
        },
        cart: cartlist,
        checkin: req.body.arrival,
        checkout: req.body.depart,
        status: 'pending',
        total: req.body.price
    });
    addtocart.save(function (err, orderdata) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("1196Error: " + err.message)
            req.flash('error', 'Unable to Add to cart... ' + err.message);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        req.flash('success', "Added to Cart!");
        console.log("success1193");
        });
        return res.redirect('/cart');
});
router.get('/cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user._id);
    qryFilter = { "user._id": req.user._id };
    Acart.find(qryFilter, function (err, cart) {
        console.log("cart1200"+cart);

        res.render('shop/cart', {
            layout: 'eshop/blank',

        });
    });
});
```